# Sorting using a custom alphabet order

Tags: c#, sorting, json.net

I'm using a third party service that returns JSON objects with a status code such as Y, N, S, D, etc. I want to sort the results according to the meaning of the status code, such that Y should come before N, which should come before S, which should come before D. What's the simplest way to accomplish this in CSharp? Performance is not of the utmost importance, as I expect to receive at most 10 results for any given request.

Example response:

```
[ { ..., status: 'Y' }, 
  { ..., status: 'D' }, 
  { ..., status: 'N' } ]
```

I'm already using JSON.NET to deserialize these into a JArray, if that helps as a starting point.

Comment: what are you using to Deserialize the json string..? have you considered doing it to a temp List<T> then adding the Items to a List<T> in the order that you are expecting..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a custom compare class

```
public class CustomSorter : IComparer
{
    public int Compare(object x, object y)
    {
        var chars = "YNSD";
        if (chars.IndexOf((char)x) < chars.IndexOf((char)y))
            return -1;
        return chars.IndexOf((char)x) > chars.IndexOf((char)y) ? 1 : 0; 
    }
}
```

Then sort the array that you have using the new sorter

Comment: This is exactly the kind of solution I was hoping for. Awesome.

Answer (score 3):

I think the easiest way would be to create a method that retrieves some kind of order key based on the letter. For example:

```
public int GetSortKey(string statusCode) {
     switch (statusCode) {
         case "Y": return 1;
         case "N": return 2;
         (etc)
     }
}
```

Then order by the array by the result of the method.

Comment: Similarly, you can convert `case constant: return another_constant` to a static dictionary and simply `return mapping[constant]`.